# Dynamic tabs don't seem to have IDs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I am dynamically adding tabs to my page using the following script:

```
var tabs = $("#tabs");
$.each(results, function(index, item) {
    tabs.tabs("add","get_tab_content.aspx?tab=" + item.key, item.value);
});
```

where `results` contains json data.

This all works find, except for when I try to get the tab `id` via the following script:

```
$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id")
```

That line returns nothing, as if an `id` is not set for the tabs in the loop above.

However, that line works fine if I manually type add tabs and ids e.g.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab" id="tab_1"><a href="tab0.htm">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tab" id="tab_2"><a href="tab1.htm">Default</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For this manual html, the line `$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id")` returns either `tab_1` or `tab_2`.

How do I get the `id` of the tab from when I create tabs using the loop above?  I am assuming I need to give them id's when adding the tabs?  But that is just an assumption.  If that is the case, how do I give them ids?

Comment: This usually occurs when you invoke "$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id")" before the tab being created. Can you show more of the source code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not add `id`s because it does not need to.

It uses the index of the tab to identify them.

Why do you need to have an id on them ?

---

**update**

To add an id for each tab you can do the following (*assuming that you use the code you provided in your question where the new tabs are added at the end by default*)

```
tabs.tabs("add","get_tab_content.aspx?tab=" + item.key, item.value)
    .find('>ul>li:last') // find the last li element, the tab we just added
    .attr('id',item.id); // use whatever id you want here ..i assumed you have an id in your json..
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7Grb8/

---

**update 2**

if you want to do it with the index, then you should use the `var selected = tabs.tabs( "option", "selected" );` as [described in the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected)

Comment: So I can tell which tab is assigned to a specific user, as each tab has different content based on the user logged in.  So does that mean it is not possible to add an id to a dynamic tab?

Comment: If it is not possible to add an id to a dynamic tab, how do I get the index of the selected tab?  Just means I will have to change the structure of my application a little to use the index instead of the id.

Comment: @oshirowanen, updated answer with some code on how to add an id.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli, thanks for the code.  Is it safe to assume that I can get the id once I've implemented your code using `$("li.ui-tabs-selected").attr("id")` for dynamic tabs?  Yes the key value from the json is the id I want the tabs to have.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli, It's working nicely.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @oshirowanen, no problem. (*and to the previous comment, yes it should work as expected, but i guess you have tested it by now..*)